# How to pipe uncompressed file to a function's arguments

Tags: bash, pipe

I am trying to extract a `.gz` file and pass it to a function that converts it to a delimited file. The `.gz` contains a `.grib2` file which I can convert to a csv using a utility called wgrib2. The problem is that I need to be able access the filename directly.

This is my nonfunctional script

```
#!/bin/bash
gunzip $1 | wgrib2 $arg1 -csv ${arg1/.grib2/.csv}
```

wgrib2 requires the three arguments: infile, format, outfile

I don't necessarily know the filename so I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<( )` operator will execute a command and redirect it's `stdout` to a named pipe that you can pass to another program.  The `$( )` operator will execute a command and insert it's `stdout` in place.  You can use these two operators will `zcat` (unzip the file to stdout) and `basename` to do what you want.

```
wgrib2 <(zcat $1) -csv $(basename $1 .grib2).csv
```